# How do i get a specific user metadata using custom metavalue outside of wordpress?

Tags: custom-field, user-meta, outside-wordpress

I need help. I need to get a user ID or email (email is can do but ID is better) based on their phone number, outside of WordPress.
I already have their phone number in a variable and  billing_phone is custom metadata in the wp_users table.
This is what I am using to load wp

```
`$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ); require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );`
```

and how I am fetching the email.

```
    `$email = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT user_email FROM wp_users WHERE billing_phone = $phone_number ");`
```

Thank you all in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Locating `wp-load.php` that way looks like you are loading it from within a plugin.  This is generally not a good idea.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: There is no meta data in `wp_users` table. And you don't need `wp-load.php` to query the database. Use plain mySQL query from your external script.

Comment: @Steve I was planning to put it in a plugin at first that is why I load it that way.

Comment: @Max lol I just noticed that i was doing that. My brain is fried. Thank for pointing that out.

Comment: If you are placing it in a plugin for wordpress why are you acting like it isn't within wordpress?

Comment: @Steve That was the plan at first until I realized that I would need it outside of wp. It was supposed to be a simple plugin that got really complicated really fast. I am sure you know coding is a step-by-step process and if you miscalculate a step all the steps after can change drastically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `billing_phone` as user meta, which is the preferred way, that query would be incorrect.  The advantage of utilizing custom user meta and adding a field for `billing_phone`  would allow you to use [`get_users()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users).

```
$user = get_users('meta_key' => 'billing_phone', 'meta_value' => $phone_number, 'fields' => 'ID');
```

The above would give you an array of User IDs that have the matching `billing_phone` meta value.

Comment: I've tried using get_users in a few different ways and it never works. The only wp function I can get to work is email_exists. I am soooo stuck on this.

Comment: Based on your query in the question I wouldn't expect get_users to work.  Get users function calling a meta key and value will only work if the user meta is registered the wordpress way and appears within the usermeta table.